# How can Tabbing move text to the Tab Stop Position, instead of selecting next row in the table?

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

Please see the screenshot beneath. The titled question is for MS Word 2016. Following [this answer's steps](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other-mso_2007/tab-key-is-selecting-next-row-in-table-instead-of/2d3137dc-d86a-4e4b-8e41-ee4e83f6ae95?auth=1) didn't solve the difficulty:

> It is the default behavior that all of the text will be selected.  To stop it from being replaced by what you then type, click on the Office button and then on Word Options and then on Advanced and in the Editing options section of the dialog, uncheck the box for "Typing replaces selected text" ) but they failed to solve this difficulty.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working in tables <kbd>Tab</kbd> will move between table cells.

In order to move to the next tab or tab stop you need to change to using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> when working in tables.